# How to mock Next.js Image component in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, storybook, nextjs-image

Next.js introduced a new `Image` component in v10 that's supposed to be a drop in replacement for the `<img>` tag.

I'm having an error when trying to view components that import `next/image` into Storybook:

`TypeError: imageData is undefined`

I have been trying to override the image object in `preview.js` (a technique I use for `next/router`, as documented [here](https://dev.to/openpatch/develop-components-for-your-next-js-site-in-isolation-with-storybook-22fh)) but I get the same error:

```js
// .storybook/preview.js

import Image from 'next/image';

Image = ({ src }) => <img src={src} />;
```

Any idea how I could override the behaviour of the `next/image` package in Storybook?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.

First we need to define an env variable with the default settings to get rid of the error. We can do this by plugging into webpack in `.storybook/main.js`:

```js
// .storybook/main.js
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.__NEXT_IMAGE_OPTS': JSON.stringify({
        deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
        imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
        domains: [],
        path: '/',
        loader: 'default',
      }),
    }));
    return config;
  },
};
```

Now we can override the default export from `next/image` package with a functional component that returns a simple `<img/>` tag.

```js
// .storybook/preview.js

import * as nextImage from 'next/image';

Object.defineProperty(nextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => {
    return <img {...props} />;
  },
});
```

I'm using the `defineProperty` static method for this ([link to MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) since I can't just assign a new value to `Image.default`.

Comment: Note that this is only compatible with webpack v4 and not v5 as of date of this comment

Comment: @OmarNasr As NextJS 11 will be using webpack 5, I am looking forward a compatible solution

Comment: From nextjs version 12.1.5 this solution appears to no longer work :(

Comment: Wrote a blog post on an alternative solution: https://dejanvasic.wordpress.com/2022/05/08/next-images-in-storybook/

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the accepted answer:

add `var webpack = require('webpack');`inside main.js